# Getting two values as single value using Beautiful soup(<strong><span>

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want below html values to be in two separately list with numeric values `list_1 = ['3,111']` and string values  `list_2 = [Hubei, china , Italy]` , but I'm getting combined list  `list = ['3,111',Hubei, china]`

please find the `HTML` source below:

```html
</div> 
<div class="external-html">
   <p><span style="color:#ffffff">3,111</span> deaths </p>
   <p><strong><span style="color:#ffffff">Hubei</span> </strong>China</p>
</div>
<div class="external-html">
   <p><span style="color:#ffffff">2,158</span> deaths </p>
   <p><strong><span style="color:#ffffff"></span> </strong>Italy</p>
</div>
<div class="external-html">
   <p><span style="color:#ffffff">853</span> deaths </p>
   <p><strong><span style="color:#ffffff"></span> </strong>Iran</p>
</div>
```

i tried using different `BeautifulSoup` methods below

```py
if (case.find('strong').find('span',style="color:#ffffff")):
    t_country_case1.append(case.find('strong').text)
else:
    t_country_case1.append('None')
```

```py
if (case.find('strong').find('span',style="color:#ffffff")):
    t_country_case1.append(case.find('strong').text)
else:
    t_country_case1.append('None')
```

is there any way to separate these values .

Comment: Hi Amar, I've corrected the format of your question. feel free to delete your previous comment in order to maintain the question well visible. as the comment section not for extend question details.

Comment: Your question isn't clear; for example, do you want `list_1` to be only `['3,111']` or `['3,111',  '2,158', '853']`?

Comment: i want all the numeric in one list ['3,111', '2,158', '853'] and all the strings in another list ['Hubei','Italy','Iran']

Comment: i didn't understand, how to include >strong< in find condition @Jack

Comment: What **exactly** is your desired output given your sample html?

Comment: Two things: first, don't post your desired output in a comment; edit your question and post it there, properly formatted. Second, the output in your comment contains data that is not included in the sample html in the question; when you edit the question, make sure the desired output is based only on the data in the question, not your actual data.

Comment: problem resolved thanks @jack